# TFS API - Display Label dialog programmatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api, tfs, label

Using TFS C# API, is it possible to open a label dialog window programmatically?
Ideally, I would like to be able to call a label by its name and scope, then have the following pop up:
[Label Dialog Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDd0Y.png)

I am using TFS 2013, and my application is a standalone one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to work with [VersionControlLabelExt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.versioncontrollabelext(v=vs.120).aspx) class in one VS Addin project. With the [VersionControlLabelExt.OpenLabel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh719027(v=vs.120).aspx) Method, you will open a new label document window, given the name, scope, and owner of the label.

Check Grant's reply in this link for a quick reference on how to get started:

[How can I open the TFS changeset details dialog view using a Visual Studio add-in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891089/how-can-i-open-the-tfs-changeset-details-dialog-view-using-a-visual-studio-add-i)

Comment: I am currently running my API operations from a standalone application, so would it be possible to do this label operation from a standalone, not an add-in? If not, how can I call on this add-in's functionality from the standalone application?