# Find Label in TFS Project

Tags: c#, tfs

I´m currently using the following code to find a branch inside a tfs-project by a specified label:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(tfsuri));

var vcs = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

string labelscope = labelscopepath;

var specifiedBranch = vcs.QueryLabels(label, labelscope, null, true);
```

But this way I only get branches when I know the name of the label. So what I need now is a methode to find all labels inside the specified project and the related branches.

So here is my TFS-structure. The branch "Branch2" has the label "Label1". Now I´d like to list all branches that have a label, including the labelname. In this case only Branch2 would be in this list.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get a list of labels first, then list branches that have a label.

```
public VersionControlLabel[] QueryLabels(String labelName,
                                         String labelScope,
                                         String owner, 
                                         bool includeItems,
                                         String filterItem,
                                         VersionSpec versionFilterItem)
```

More details please refer this blog: [Displaying the labels on a file, including label comments](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2005/10/25/displaying-the-labels-on-a-file-including-label-comments/) You could even display Label dialog programatically following this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33111448/tfs-api-display-label-dialog-programatically).

Comment: Okay I´ve got it. You have to set labelName "null" to get all labels. Thank you Patrick-MSFT the blog-post you´ve posted helped me to understand that.