# Restrict particular work item to link with changeset in TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

Is there is a possibility to restrict particular work item say Task:1234 to be linked with any changeset.

Developer should get prompt/msg if they try to add their changes for that workitem id.

Please let me know the solution for this query.

Comment: No. What is the situation you're encountering where this is desired behavior?

Comment: This should be the behaviour. When the user tries to check-in there pending changes, under related work item they can select any workitem. SO here I want to restrict them when they select some selected workitem ids like 123, 768 etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is not any build-in feature to restrict particular work item to link with changeset.

Even with the permission setting, we could also not configure related permission for a particular workitem.

As a workaround, if you want to do this during the [check in option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41608612/find-label-in-tfs-project), you could use customize check in policy raise up a policy warning, remember user do not associate changeset with specific work item. As for how to create customize check in policy, please refer this blog: [Creating TFS Custom Check-in Policy](https://blog.devart.com/creating-tfs-custom-check-in-policy-part-1.html)